# Copy property values from an object to another javascripy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm stucked in this js problem. I have this object of objects here:

```
   Object { cpu: {…}, gpu: {…}, hdd: {…}, ram: {…}, mb: {…} }
​
cpu: Object { id: 13, brand: "Intel", model: "i3-12100", … }
​
gpu: Object { id: 2, brand: "Nvidia", model: "GTX 1660", … }
```

and I'd like to change the values of `gpu` with those of an other Object

```
Object { gpu: {…} }
​
gpu: Object { id: 9, brand: "Nvidia", model: "RTX 3050", … }
```

How can i do that? I tried with `Object.assign()` but once I print the values of the first Object of objects values of `gpu` do not change.

Answer (score 1):

Try the spread operator:

```
gpu: Object{...anotherObject}
```